# postfix mail server not configured in outlook

Tags: postfix

I have configured postfix mail server with squirrel mail web client. I'm able to success send out mail through squirrel mail/web mail but when I tried to configure it in outlook then smtp is not test success.

```
error: Snd test e-mail message: None of the authentication methods supported by this client are supported by your server.
```

Please let me know where I'm wrong below is the configuration detail from my server:

```
[root@mailserver ~]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = agilis.com
myhostname = mailserver.agilis.com
mynetworks = 192.168.6.0/24, 58.68.50.51, 209.44.115.63, 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relayhost = mail.agilisinternational.com
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
[root@mailserver ~]#
[root@mailserver ~]# netstat -tanp|grep 25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      23184/master
tcp        0      0 :::25                       :::*                        LISTEN      23184/master
tcp        0      0 :::36125                    :::*                        LISTEN      1270/rpc.statd
```

Comment: You are using the wrong port. Outgoing mail from Outlook should be sent to port 587 on your mail server.

Comment: ok please let me know the parameters how could I define it.

Answer (score 1):

Your postfix server should have authentication, encryption and submission enabled. Right now it has none of these. `smtp` parameters are postfix's client (sending) side. `smtpd` are postfix's server (receiving side).

Your `/etc/postfix/master.cf` should contain a line (perhaps appropriately wrapped for readability) like the following.

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

This causes postfix to listen on port 587 (submission), log distinctly, and require authentication and encryption.

You'll have to do additional work in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to enable encryption. At minimum `smtpd_tls_cert_file` and `smtpd_tls_key_file`.

You'll also have to setup some sort of authentication backend, I recommend hooking into your existing authentication infrastructure (i.e. whatever Squirelmail is using). The details will depend on your backend. http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html

While it is possible to do authentication without encryption, doing so is incompetently negligent.